# How does the pulse.Shiftphase instruction in Qiskit Pulse work?

Tags: programming, qiskit, quantum-gate, superconducting-quantum-computing, openpulse

I have some questions regarding the mechanism of Qiskit `pulse.ShiftPhase` instruction:

1. Does it work like a Phase Shift $P(\theta)=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\0 & e^{i\theta}
   \end{bmatrix}$ gate, a Global Phase Shift $Ph(\theta)=\begin{bmatrix} e^{i\theta} & 0 \\0 & e^{i\theta}
   \end{bmatrix}$ gate, or a $R_z(\theta)=\begin{bmatrix} e^{-i\theta/2} & 0 \\0 & e^{i\theta/2}
   \end{bmatrix}$ gate?
2. I read that when I apply a `ShiftPhase` it'd affect all the pulses following, meaning everytime I apply a pulse there will be a phase shift gate right? So if I only want to apply only one RZ/PS/Global PS gate should I apply a reversal phase shift after a pulse, or would that equivalently mean I have applied a PS/GPS/RZ($ -\theta$) gate?
3. How is the free Z rotation tracked by software in the case of a qutrit (3 energy levels) or more, and how does `ShiftPhase` work in this case?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First note that your $P(\theta)$ and $R_z(\theta)$ gates are the same up to a global phase, so you will not be able to distinguish them.

Now, according to [qiskit.pulse.ShiftPhase documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.pulse.ShiftPhase.html):

> The qubit phase is tracked in software, enabling instantaneous, nearly error-free Z-rotations by using a ShiftPhase to update the frame tracking the qubit state.

So the `ShiftPhase` pulse implements a $R_z(\theta)$ gate (or $P(\theta)$ as they are the same).

If you want to shift the phase only for one gate, you will have to apply a $P(-\theta)$ (via `ShiftPhase`) just after the gate. It is likely that the `ShiftPhase` will need a positive phase, as it should increase the phase according to the documentation:

> The `ShiftPhase` instruction causes $\phi$ to be increased by the instruction’s phase operand.

In this case, you can use $P(-\theta) = P(2\pi - \theta)$ and still apply a `ShiftPhase`.

About your third question, the software (`qiskit` here?) is not aware of `qutrits`. It just "attach" to every pulse a given phase, pre-computed when the quantum circuit is transformed to a `Schedule`, and executes each pulse with its attached phase. There is no notion of $n$-level state here, it just impact the pulses. If your pulses explore a $3$-level state then so be it, but I do not think the phase-tracking part changes in any way.